# Collection value is not getting iterated in passed Query?

Tags: java, sql

Below is my Code..

```
while(obt.hasNext()){

        try{
            Object itrvalue = obt.next();
            String sql2 ="select entryDt,Student_Name,Class_Div_Name,ReceiptNo from       test where ReceiptNo = '"+itrvalue+"'";
            System.out.println("Receipt No --"+itrvalue);
            stat =  con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            rs=stat.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            Date datevalue = rs.getDate(1);
            String name = rs.getString(2);
            String CDN = rs.getString(3);
            String RNO = rs.getString(4);
            System.out.println("Date is ---"+datevalue);
            System.out.println("Student Name ---"+name);
            System.out.println("Coloumn Div No ---"+CDN);
            System.out.println("Receipt No ---"+RNO);
            rs.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){};
        }
```

Output : -

```
Receipt No  --S00000001234
Date is ---2013-06-10 
Student Name ---ABC XYZ 
Coloumn Div No ---VI - C 
Receipt No ---S00000001234
Receipt No --S00000001234 
Receipt No --S00000001235
Receipt No --S00000001236
Receipt No --S00000001237 
Receipt No --S00000001238
Receipt No --S00000001239
```

Every iteration value's are getting changed. But in Current SQL query it's getting passed only 1st value remaining iteration values are getting displayed, but not getting passed in SQL Query. As per output you can see I have received data only `S00000001234` and I want same details of all Receipt No.

Comment: obt is another ResultSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have raised an exception. Try this code instead:

```
String sql2 = "select entryDt,Student_Name,Class_Div_Name,ReceiptNo from test where ReceiptNo = ?";
PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql2);

try {
    while (obt.hasNext()) {
        try {
            Object itrvalue = obt.next();
            System.out.println("Receipt No --" + itrvalue);
            stat.setObject(1, itrvalue);
            rs = stat.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            Date datevalue = rs.getDate(1);
            String name = rs.getString(2);
            String CDN = rs.getString(3);
            String RNO = rs.getString(4);
            System.out.println("Date is ---" + datevalue);
            System.out.println("Student Name ---" + name);
            System.out.println("Coloumn Div No ---" + CDN);
            System.out.println("Receipt No ---" + RNO);
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (stat != null) {
        stat.close();
    }
}
```